# Where should I put my utils for a model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a question about organization and best-practices in Laravel. Let's say I have a model PromoCode.
I take the user input (let's say he pick the "percent" option and the "25" option). In the database, I want to put "25%".

So, what I would do is that I would take the input, make a function that handles the different cases and return the value. However, where should I put this special function? It is specific to this model, I won't reuse it anywhere else.

Should I put it in the Model class? The controller? Make another whole class just to put this function/util?

I just want to know the best practice about that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Keep It Simple** principle should be applied.

If the Model class is not a very large class then I would prefer to keep in with the class.

2. **Keep it clean and small**

If the Model class is fairly large such that it may become cumbersome to maintain or large according your own style or taste - put the function in a **trait** and use the trait in the Model class.

An added advantage would be that if you ever require the functionality in some other area of the application it becomes very easy to use the trait - **DRY**

3. **Keep Unrelated tucked away in helper file**

If the function is totally unrelated to the core domain or logic of your application you can also write it in a `helper.php` file which you can autoload via composer.json

```json
{
    ""autoload": {
        "psr-4": { ... },
        "files": [
            "helper.php"
        ]
}
```